# Gold linker: specify alignment of sections

Tags: c++, linux, linker, ld, binutils

I want to specify alignment for some sections. For `ld 2.20.0` the following approach works:

- create a linker script containing only the sections that should be aligned, e.g.:

  ```
  SECTIONS
  {
      .data ALIGN(0x40): { *(.data) }

      .text ALIGN(0x40): { *(.text) }

      .plt ALIGN(0x10): { *(.plt) }
  }
  ```
- then link with:

  ```
  -rpath-link=/path/to/LinkerScript.ld /path/to/LinkerScript.ld
  ```

  e.g. include the script in rpath-link and also pass it as one of the object files.

Now, when linking in the same way using `gold 2.23.1`, the script is rejected with this error:

```
LinkerScript.ld: SECTIONS seen after other input files; try -T/--script
```

So gold wants me to specify a complete linker script, however I only want to change a couple attributes. Is this possible?

I have already tried:

- Passing the script with the `-T` option. This produces a broken executable that fails to start. As I understand this is because `-T` only accepts complete linker scripts, while the above is just an "annotation" to the existing script.
- In the same vein, when passing the script with the `-T` option to `ld 2.20.0` it fails to link since some sections are unspecified. It is not a "complete" linker script for my use case.
- So I have tried obtaining a complete linker script. `ld --verbose` will print the default linker script. I had to remove a couple of symbols that were not understood by `gold`, afterwards the executable produced with the `-T/path/to/LinkerScript.ld` option didn't work anymore.
- Unfortunately `gold` has no option to show its default linker script (it doesn't use any).
- The man pages do not specify how to change alignment for the case above with a parameter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution that solves my problem.

- Alignment of data and text sections can be achieved by including an assembler file with dummy alignments. The alignment of a section will be the maximum alignment sepcified anywhere, so at a minimum it will have this alignment.

  Example file align.s (compile with your assembler and include the object file in your link):

```
    .section .text
    .balign 0x40

    .section .data
    .balign 0x40

    .end
```

- The gold linker aligns PLT and GOT entries by their sizes (16 and 8 bytes, respectively). This is sufficient for my use case.